# Adding tags to a specific phrase on each line

Tags: sed

So, basically I have lines like these:

```
ILU1910\ilu0001 “ My hand is broken , ” said the sailor , “ and smoked the pipe . ” 
ILU1910\ilu0001 “ It is going make life harder for us , ” he said .
```

And I want them to look like this:

```
<ignore>ILU1910\ilu0001</ignore> “ My hand is broken , ” said the sailor , “ and smoked the pipe . ” 
<ignore>ILU1910\ilu0001</ignore> “ It is going make life harder for us , ” he said .
```

Basically at the start of each line there is ILU1910/ilu0001 and I want to add `<ignore>` at the start and `</ignore>` at the end of said phrase.

I tried to use this to make it work by using this command:

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/^\([^A-Za-z0-9]\+ \)/<ignore>\1<\/ignore>/g'
```

But it does not seem to work. I am using the terminal on my MacBook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easily done using `sed`.

```
sed 's/ILU1910\\ilu0001/<ignore>&<\/ignore>/' file.txt
```

Since there is only one pattern to match, you can do it more easily using `&`.  If you want to use `cat`, it'll be

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/ILU1910\\ilu0001/<ignore>&<\/ignore>/'
```

In your attempt, you are working with anything non-alphanumeric `[^A-Za-z0-9]`.  You could modify your pattern to anything non-blank using `[^ ]*` as follows:

```
sed 's/^[^ ]*/<ignore>&<\/ignore>/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to edit a file in-place, you could script the changes with `ed`:

```
ed -s file.txt <<< $'1,$s,ILU1910\\\\ilu0001,<ignore>ILU1910\\\\ilu0001</ignore>,\nw\nq'
```

This calls `ed` in `-s` silent mode and sends it a list of instructions in a quoted here-string:

- `1,$s,ILU1910\\\\ilu0001,<ignore>ILU1910\\\\ilu0001</ignore>,` - on every line (`1,$`), search and replace (`s, ... , ... ,`) the first part with the second part. Because there's a forward slash in the replacement text, I changed the typical `/` delimiter to a comma (`,`), since there were no commas in the search or replacement text. Because backslashes are interpreted by both the shell's quoting and by `ed`, they must be doubled-up twice, which is how one `\` turned into four `\\\\`.
- `w` - write the file back to disk
- `q` - quit ed